# How to Protect my JSON Server Data in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json

How to Protect my JSON Server Data in angularJS?

In the Controller I'm using the URL of the JSON Server Data, So, How Can I Protect it from the Client Side?

My JSON Server Data URL is http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php

My Source Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="SuperFunction('{{x.Name}}')">{{ x.Country }}</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function (response) { $scope.names = response.data.records; });
    $scope.SuperFunction = function (id) {
        alert(id);
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean *to protect*?

Comment: The Hacker Can easily access the JS file, from that he can easily get the JSON Data using the specified URL. How to Protect the Data from the Hacker?

Comment: You can't _protect_ anything inside of client-side JavaScript, the best you can do is _obfuscate_.

Comment: "The Hacker"...in this case you mean user. That is the beauty of the web: view source. You can see and learn exactly what is happening in front of you. There are ways to obfuscate this data, but do so knowing that you are violating one of the tenets of the web. TBL created the web this way for all of us, not so you could profit of closed/siloed/proprietary nonsense.... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can't protect your Frontend code, it is visible to the user / hacker!

The best way of protecting information is a server side authentification (login)

But the api and the api calls (over dev tools) are always visible!